# Turning figure or axes title off

Tags: python, matplotlib

Via `ax.xaxis.grid(False)` one can 'turn off/on' the grid.

Is there an equivalently pythonic way for a figure suptitle or an axes title?
Something in the style of
`ax.title(False)`

I want to write a function which is supposed to take an argument to determine whether the figure produced has a title or not (see example).

Of course, inside the function I could use a conditional statement, however, that seems rather unpythonic.

Minimal example:

```
def f(title=False, xgrid=False):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    if title == False:    # I consider this unpythonic
        ax.set_title("")
    else:
        ax.set_title("<default_title>")

    ax.xaxis.grid(xgrid)    # I want this, only for titles

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you want something beyond `ax.get_title()` and `ax.set_title()`?

Comment: Yes, something to "toggle" a pre-defined title on and off, in a sense

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem. Perhaps you can add the solution you consider "unpythonic" to your question?

Comment: ok thanks for the example. Why not just replace the title argument of your function with the title you actually want (defaulting to `""`) and then set it every time?

Comment: More Pythonic would be `if not title:` instead of `if title == False:`

Comment: @tomjn That would also be an idea, I did not think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
ax.set_title("default title") # always set a default title
ax.title.set_visible(title) # set on or off
```

To toggle, you could do

```py
ax.title.set_visible(not ax.title.get_visible())
```